# Как при внесении комитов в Git Lab не затронуть чужую работу?

Tags: git, gitlab

уважаемые специалисты!

Новичок в Git и из штудирования документации не понял:

1. Достаточно ли для того, чтобы своими изменениями не "потереть" чужую работу делать git pull перед тем, как сделать Git Push?
2. Что нужно делать, чтобы твои редакции не нанесли ущерба действиям других разработчиков?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: 1. при обычном использовании git ничего не "трет", а только добавляет 2. это скорее вопрос организационного характера

Comment: Скажите, а какой должна быть безопасная для проекта последовательность действий? Например, если я правильно понял, я могу объединить свой brunch с основным (master) и тогда основной (с которым работают все) изменится по моей ветке.. Но ведь пока я ее делал туда уже могли быть внесены изменения..

Comment: Тогда при пуше будет сообщение Push creates new remote heads! и он не выполнится пока вы не подтяните новые изменения и не смерджите с ними.

Comment: "Что нужно делать, чтобы твои редакции не нанесли ущерба действиям других разработчиков?" - общаться, общаться и ещё раз общаться с коллегами.

Comment: "Что нужно делать, чтобы твои редакции не нанесли ущерба действиям других разработчиков?" Забрать все изменения, убедиться что нет конфликтов (если есть - устранить). Потом проверить проект на работоспособность. Ну и потом мержиться с основной веткой.

Comment: вот в "убедится, что нет конфликтов" - это очень сложно. Можно потрогать код в одном месте, а потом окажется, что совсем в другом месте выстрелит.